# Getting user information using either user.login or user.id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, types

So I have a url like the following

```
localhost/users/:id/posts
```

which gives the posts of that particular user. Now this id can be either his login (which is a string) or the id (user.id) which is technically an Integer but `params[:id]` is always a string. So how do I implement this an action.

```
@user = params[:id].is_a?(String) ? User.find_by_login(params[:id]) : User.find(params[:id])
```

The above code miserably fails since `params[:id]` is always a string. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: By saying this: "Now this id can be either his login (which is a string) or the id (user.id) which is technically an Integer", you agree that your usernames cannot have purely numeric logins, without you having to specify different lookups for each.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I've done this, I've actually had two separate controller actions-- `show` and `show_by_login`. I feel like it's less unpredictable that way, and I have more control.

Be sure to enforce uniqueness of your logins, index them, and if `show_by_login` can't find the record you have to `raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` yourself.

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.xml  { render :xml => @user.to_xml }
    end
  end

  def show_by_login
    @user = User.find_by_login(params[:login])
    unless @user
      raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    end

    render :action => 'show'
  end
```

Comment: This is the only way you can allow purely numeric logins and be able to search with both.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression:

```
@user = params[:id] =~ /^\d+$/ ? User.find(params[:id]) : User.find_by_login(params[:id])
```

Comment: But, as the saying goes, "now you have two problems" (http://bit.ly/1G8lgA) -- so my username cannot be 8675309? It's my favorite song!

Comment: Yeah, but that's more of a problem with the design (using params[:id] for both ID and username) rather than regular expressions. ;)

Comment: @Mikael : Apparently, yes. But not quite. You can always use 2 separate paths to specify what to search with.

Answer (score 0):

So long as you don't allow any logins to consist purely of digits, you could write your own finder/named_scope.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :find_by_id_or_login, lambda {|id_or_login|
    { :conditions => ["id = ? OR login = ?", id_or_login, id_or_login]  }
  }
end

@user = User.find_by_id_or_login(params[:id])
```

Comment: You have to be sure to enforce that rule (that a login cannot have only digits) at all places that a login can be set. Otherwise, there is potential for returning the wrong user's info. Especially if a user can change their login, and just enumerate through the user ids.

Comment: @Ben, if you've read the solution you'll notice the first sentence addresses that. Although, I didn't think the explanation was necessary, thanks for elaborating on why this solution depends on no being numeric.